# Sections without cells in uitableview

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Just saw a view in iOS settings page, wondering how to create it, it looks like a UITableViewController with 'static' contents. How to make text sections just like there are below 'twitter' cell. In my app I want to add an 'Activity Indicator View'. But looks like when I add more sections to my view an oval 'cell' comes with it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "text sections" below the Twitter cell are just Section Footers.
In your TableView's datasource override this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return @"This is my footer's text!";
}
```

Also if you want a custom view as footer, override:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // myFooterView is a custom view. Allocated and initialized
    return myFooteView;
}
```